# Объявить >> и <<, как дружественные функции

Tags: c++, строки, перегрузка-операторов, c++14, дружественная-функция

:)

Возникла проблема 
"Бесконечный ввод", то есть вызывается консоль, но, видимо, что-то циклится
После нажатия клавиши Enter курсор переводся на следующую строку, ввод не прекращается

Помогите, пожалуйста
Не могу понять, в чем проблема
Спасибо! :D

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class st {
private:
char stroka[10000];
public:
friend istream &operator >> (istream &input, st&d) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        if (d.stroka[i] != '\0') {
            input >> d.stroka[i];
        }
    }
    return input;
}

friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const st&d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        if (d.stroka[i] != '\0') {
            output << d.stroka[i] << "  ";
        }
    }
    return output;
}

};

int main() {
st a;
cin >> a;
cout << a;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, что вы хотите сказать, например, этим:

```
if (d.stroka[i] != '\0') {
```

Попробуйте - это случайно не то, что вы хотите?

```
class st {
private:
    char stroka[10000];
public:
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &input, st&d)
    {
        return input.getline(d.stroka,10000);
    }

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const st&d)
    {
        return output << d.stroka;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать input.getline как вариант

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class st {
private:
    char stroka[10000];
public:
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &input, st&d) {
        int i = 0;
        input.getline(d.stroka, 10000);
        return input;
    }

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const st&d) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(d.stroka); i++) {
                output << d.stroka[i] << "  ";
        }
        return output;
    }

};

int main() {

    st a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```